# delete from list in python

Tags: python, list

in a Python program, I need to define a list from another one, and the delete an element from the new list, it also removes it from the other list. does anyone know how to counter that ?

below, an example :

```
source = [4, 5, 6]
new = source
new.remove(5)
print(new) # output [4, 6] has wanted
print(source) # output [4, 6] but wanted [4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

use `copy()`:

```
source = [4, 5, 6]
new = source.copy()
new.remove(5)
print(new) #output: [4, 6]
print(source) #output: [4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `new = source` both variables point to the same place in your storage. What you need to use is:

```
source = [4, 5, 6]
new = source.copy()
new.remove(5)
print(new) # output [4, 6] has wanted
print(source) # output [4,5, 6] but wanted [4, 5, 6]
```

This will copy the elements inside the source and assign it to the new variable.

If your list contains mutable things such as objects, you should use a deep copy.

```
from copy import deepcopy
new = deepcopy(source)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.copy()` because when you use `new=source` the entry point will be same. So if you delete one item from one list it will delete it from both.

Code:

```
source = [4, 5, 6]
new = source.copy()
new.remove(5)
print(new)
print(source)
```

Output:

```
[4, 6]
[4, 5, 6]
```